# notice trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

what is the error in this please help!

here is the query from mysql :

> ```
> public function stgradu($condition=">=50"){
>     $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT
>     courses_has_schedule.mark as mark,
>     Sum(courses.crs_hours) as total_hrs
>     FROM
>     courses_has_schedule
>     Inner Join courses ON courses_has_schedule.crs_id = courses.crs_id
>     Inner Join schedule ON schedule.sch_id = courses_has_schedule.sch_id
>     Inner Join student ON student.st_id = schedule.st_id
>
>     where
>     student.st_id=? AND courses_has_schedule.mark $condition");
>     $stmt->execute(array($this->getCurrentStudent(true)));
>     return $stmt->fetchAll();
> }
> ```

when i run this if statement :

```
$stgr = $dataService->stgradu(">=50");
if(($stgr->total_hrs==7) AND ($stgradu->mark >= 50)) {
  echo Yes*";   
}else
  echo "No";
```

when i run the app its gives me  this error 
`(( Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\samer\stgr.php on line >12))`

please help all!

Comment: check `$stgr` this varibale, this might be a 2-dimensional array. Print this `$stgr` using `var_dump();`

Comment: $stgr->total_hrs This is probably no object.

Comment: `PDOStatement::fetchAll — Returns an *array* containing all of the result set rows `

Comment: @Xatenev no no actually not `$stgr->total_hr`, but `$stgr` itself

Comment: Ah k- well u_mulder just gave him the answer.

Comment: Girls, how do you know what mode he set when instantiating PDO???

Comment: @Scorpion What do you mean? Hes using his function stgradu which returns an array (fetchAll();)

Comment: `fetchAll` can fetch))) not arrays, but not many people set some attributes in `PDO::__construct`. So we can consider this is the default situation until anything else defined)

Comment: thanx all.. i knew it by my self :P the syntax should be... 

return $stmt->fetchAll()[0];

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` to `fetchAll()` because it returns an associative array by default.

```
public function stgradu($condition=">=50"){
    $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT
    courses_has_schedule.mark as mark,
    Sum(courses.crs_hours) as total_hrs
    FROM
    courses_has_schedule
    Inner Join courses ON courses_has_schedule.crs_id = courses.crs_id
    Inner Join schedule ON schedule.sch_id = courses_has_schedule.sch_id
    Inner Join student ON student.st_id = schedule.st_id

    where
    student.st_id=? AND courses_has_schedule.mark $condition");
    $stmt->execute(array($this->getCurrentStudent(true)));
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

If you are supposed to get only one row then change it to `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` and your code should run fine.

Comment: thanx all.. i knew it by my self  :P
the syntax should be... 

return $stmt->fetchAll()[0]; 

:) :)

Answer (score 0):

fetchAll returns an array and you are trying to acces it like an object. Try this:
    if(($stgr['total_hrs']==7) AND ($stgradu['mark'] >= 50)) {

Answer (score -1):

thanx all.. i knew it by my self :P the syntax should be...

> return $stmt->fetchAll()[0];